# How to easily delete swap file placed in another directory (vim)?

Tags: vim

I had a session with 7 files opened in vim. After accidental crash and reloading the session each file gives `E325: ATTENTION` explaining that the files are newer than swap ones! I don't remember how these files become newer that the original swap ones, but for now it doesn't matter, because I want to learn how to handle this case.

I think, the solution would be simple if swap files was placed along the files itself (eg `.filename.swp` next to `filename`). Because I could remove it just by `:!rm .%.swp`.

However I changed the default directory of swap files, which is now set to `directory=~/.vim/tmp/swp//`. So the question is how can I get the full pathname to the swap file. For example:

```
vim /home/timur/code/src/project/main.go

E325: ATTENTION
...
Swap file "~/.vim/tmp/swp//%home%timur%code%src%project%main.go.swp" already exists!
[O]pen Read-Only, (E)dit anyway, (R)ecover, (Q)uit, (A)bort

E or R

After I opened the buffer I want to type something like this:
:remove *swapname*
or using a shortcut:
<leader>rw
```

I've read the docs and found the command to show current swap file name: `:swapname`. But it seems the output name isn't fit to passing it into `rm` command, because there is additional slash before the swap name. For example:

```
Actual file:
/home/timur/.vim/tmp/swp/%home%timur%code%own%src%file
The output of :swapname (adds odd slash before swap name)
/home/timur/.vim/tmp/swp//%home%timur%code%own%src%file.swp
                         ^ ???
```

To put it simple: **how to get direct/explicit path to swap file of current buffer?**

Comment: What exactly is the problem? You want to remove a file with `rm`. You know the name and location of the file. What am I missing?

Comment: 1) I don't want to type too looong names like `/home/timur/.vim/tmp/swp/%home%timur%code%own%src%file.swp` even if I know the location. 2) I don't know how to get direct path to swap file (as I mentioned `:swapname` don't give the actual name of file).

Comment: 1) Copy/paste. 2) Yes, it does. Have you tried it?

Comment: 1) It is not what I want (I don't want to manage every deletion for 7 files).  2) Yes I tried, `rm` gives an error (file or folder doesn't exists).

Comment: `rm ~/.vim/tmp/swp/*.swp`?

Comment: `:!find ~/.vim/tmp/swp -iname '*.swp' -delete` -- pentakill!

Comment: What about `*.swo` a `*.swn`, etc.? :-)

Comment: Ok, got it) You guys offer a little bit "strange" solution - just delete all swap files and that's all. But what if my files was crashed? I don't use `backup`, so before make any unconscious deletions I need to load each file separately to check if everything ok and only then make some action - hence delete "on demand") You can claim: "ok, just open and check all of your files and delete! It's simple!", but sometimes I open too much files from different folders so I can just forget "to check" some of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inspired by [issue 355](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/355), here is your mapping

```
nnoremap <silent> <Leader>rw :call DeleteSwapFile()<CR>

function! DeleteSwapFile()
        redir => s:a
        exe ':sil sw'
        redir end
        let b:swapname = s:a[1:]
        call delete(b:swapname)
endfunction
```

- [`:h redir`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/various.txt.html#%3Aredir)

Comment: What is `s:a` and `:sil sw`? (sil = silent, but what about `sw`) Please, give a little explanation. I don't like a "magic  code")

Comment: `sw` is short for `swapname`, `s:` means [script variable](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#script-variable). Sorry, I thought that it was easy to find it in help.

Comment: Hm..that is interesting!) Thank you)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind solving the problem using a vim plugin try [**Recover.vim**](https://github.com/chrisbra/Recover.vim) plugin.

When opening a new file, it checks if a swapfile is already present. 
If so gives two additionals options:

- `[D]elete`: delete the swapfile (i use this option very rarely)
- `D(i)ff`: compare the recover version of the file and the current version. If they are the same it asks you if you want to delete the swap file. If they are not the same open a vimdiff session between to visually compare the differences.

Really a must have.